# Error: C6386: Buffer overrun while writing to 'newArr': the writable size is 'int current_size*1' bytes, but '2' bytes might be written

Tags: c++

The code does print out. But it's giving that error. The objective is to print it out as an example:
4 as: aaaa
8 as: aaaaaaaa
12 as: aaaaaaaaaaaa
16 as: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int current_size = 4;
int resize_step = 4;

void add_number(char* &arr, int count, char x){
   if(count == current_size){
       current_size += resize_step;
       char* newArr = new char[current_size];
       
       for(int i=0;i<count;i++) newArr[i] = arr[i];
       delete arr;
       arr = newArr;
   }
   arr[count-1] = x;
}


//After
int main(){
   char* arr = new char[current_size];
   for(int count=0;count<4;count++){
       add_number(arr, count+1, '1' + count);
   }
   for(int i=0;i<4;i++) cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't do what you expected to be done.. if by error you mean that it fails an online test case, that's why. Your're leaking memory allocated by first new expression and you're comparing the iteration index with size of array

Comment: Since normally in C++ raw pointers for owned memory, C-Style arrays, new, char* for strings are NOT used, you should explain, if you must use these elements for practicing, or, if you are allowed to use the C++ ````std::string````. Then solution will become extremely simply.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie maybe you are right, but I dont see it. I understand the code like this: The iteration index `count` is the new size of the array and the array allocated from the first `new` is deallocated in the function, only memory from the last `new` leaks

Comment: cannot reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/enendE (though if there is UB, I don't expect it to be reproducible)

Comment: It's a false positive from the static analysis tool. (And it's a warning, not an error.)

Comment: Arrays have to be freed with `delete[]` (note the brackets), not `delete`. So this is leaking memory

Comment: @dave It's worse than a leak; it has undefined behaviour.

Comment: can you clarify what is the actual objective? If you merely want to print n-times the character `a` then you need a single line of code. Otherwise I am afraid this question will be closed as typo, because `delete[]` vs `delete` is the only wrong thing I can spot ( + leaking the last array but thats a minor)

Comment: @dave: It doesn't leak memory in any implementation that I have seen. It may be undefined behaviour, but it doesn't leak memory :-)

Answer (score 0):

So I have rewritten the code. but the expected output is:
Expected answer:
4 as: aaaa
8 as: aaaaaaaa
12 as: aaaaaaaaaaaa
16 as: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

I am only getting the first line **4 as aaaa**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int current_size = 4;
int resize_step = 4;

//This functions add the value x at the last position in the array
//The count of elements is indicated by the variable count
//If the array is already at maximum it resizes
//The array starts at current_size size and resizes in resize_step intervals
void add_number(char*& arr, int count, char x)
{
    //Your code starts here
    arr = new char[current_size];
    for (int i = 0; i < current_size; i++)
    {
        //arr[i] = x;
        if (count >= current_size)
        {
            current_size += resize_step;
            char* array2 = new char[current_size - resize_step];
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(array2); j++)
            {
               array2[j] = arr[j];
            }
            delete[](arr);
            arr = array2;
        }
        arr[i] = x;
    }
}
int main() {
    char* arr = new char[current_size];
    char x = 'a';
    int element = 8;
    add_number(arr, element, x);
    for (int i = 0; i < current_size; i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is more wrong than your original code, eg why do you now allocate an array with some size as before when you want to add elements `new char[current_size - resize_step];` ?